# How do I create an XML node such as "image:image" with no xmnls attribute? C#

Tags: c#, xml, image, nodes

I have an image sitemap that has nodes like this:

```
<image:image xmlns:image="image">
  <image:loc>
    https://website
  </image:loc>
  <image:caption/>
  <image:title>logo72x72</image:title>
</image:image>
```

This is the code that creates it:

```
XmlNode imageNode = doc.CreateElement("image", "image", "image");
XmlNode imageLocNode = doc.CreateElement("image", "loc", "image");                        
imageLocNode.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode(imageUrl));
imageNode.AppendChild(imageLocNode);

XmlNode imageCaptionNode = doc.CreateElement("image", "caption", "image");
imageCaptionNode.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode(imageCaption));
imageNode.AppendChild(imageCaptionNode);

XmlNode imageTitleNode = doc.CreateElement("image", "title", "image");
imageTitleNode.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode(imageTitle));
imageNode.AppendChild(imageTitleNode);

urlNode.AppendChild(imageNode);
```

However, in the Google Search Console I'm getting an error because of the image tag, which does not match Google's documentation. According to Google, the image tag should look like `<image:image>`, not `<image:image xmlns:image="image">`.

I changed the code to `doc.CreateElement("image", "image")` but that changed the output to `<image xmlns:image="image">` (it removed the part I wanted, and left the xmnls). How do I prevent the xmlns attribute from being added?

EDIT: The namespace is declared in the root of my document:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
    xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
```

Comment: You need to declare the proper namespace somewhere. Check the documentation, there is always a declaration and the URL must also match.

Comment: The namespace is declared in the root of my document: <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">

Comment: You need to pass the Uri_ for image not the string image as the 3rd param of createelement

Comment: what is the Uri_ for image?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the correct *namespace* for each of your elements.  The namespace is `http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1`, not `image`.

```
doc.CreateElement("image", "image", "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1")`
```

`image` is a namespace *prefix*, and a namespace prefix must be declared by `xmlns:image="..."` in the element or any ancestor element.  In your case it is declared in the root of the document, so this won't be added a second time.